# How to generate a binary based folder comparison two sync directories?

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a simple scenario where I need to generate releases for some java based software. What I've been doing manually is:

1- Build the software
2- Copy all that is needed to a "release dir"
3- Compress the file

Now I have added CI (jenkins) to create builds for me. Then I tried rsync to update a base install dir (which contains the last build). The problem with RSYNC is it uses timestamps. Since I just build a new version, all timestamps have changed. I there something I can do to compare the files in binary mode?

### EDIT

This is what I did. For now, src1 and src2 are the same. The only difference is the timestamp as src2 is a copy of src1. Then, rsync copies all the files to dst. I was expecting dst to be empty.

> rsync -av --progress --stats --compare-dest=../src1/ src2/ dst/

So I tried the following. I generated a copy of src1 with the same timestamp and when I execute the same command, dst is empty. Which led me to believe rsync uses timestamps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to use option, otherwise, the default is a quick timestamp and size comparison

> --checksum

Comment: Were you able to make this work? I have the same use-case and using `--checksum` also doesn't help. I'm getting all the files for the new build, even those which should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

rsync effectively compares the files in binary mode, it only transmits contents if a difference in binary content is found.

As I understand it, the checks on modification time (and size) are used to select files for comparison.

rsync has a `--size-only` option

Comment: I edited a bit my post. I read that rsync compares the files, but I think timestamp difference is enough to send a fresh copy. I want to force a binary comparison.

Comment: Maybe rsync doesn't do byte-range comparison for local copies? When you think about it, to checksum the files it has to read both fully. To do a copy it has to read one fully and write one fully. There may not be a lot to be gained?